# Restrict <p> to one line and ellipsize when necessary?

Tags: css

I have this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Some long text here</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

is there a way to get the p text to be restricted to a single line, and have it ellipsize if it's going to be wider than the parent container?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://kswedberg.github.io/jquery-expander/demo/index.html) is the exact one you are looking for. Its a jQuery plugin. Once you add this plugin, all you have to do is wrap it in a div like this. It automatically wraps based on the text size you specify.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="expandable">
        <p>Some long text here</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 26):

You can [restrict the text to one line](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp) using CSS.

```
<p style="white-space: nowrap;"></p>
```

**EDIT:** [According to quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) there's apparently a `text-overflow: ellipsis`. I've never used this and don't really know anything about it, but you should look into it.

Comment: Ok I'm trying this, seems to work except in FF: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/ellipsis-html-css/

Answer (score 15):

CSS has `white-space: nowrap` (gives you single line) and `text-overflow: ellipsis` which should do exactly what you want. Unfortunately, `text-overflow: ellipsis` isn't supported by all browsers ([Firefox being the exception in this case](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/ellipsis-html-css/)).

Devon Govett wrote a [ellipsis plugin](https://gist.github.com/digulla/5796047) for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which solves that.

Original blog: [Text-overflow: ellipsis for Firefox via jQuery](http://web.archive.org/web/20130326060624/http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/text-overflow-ellipsis-for-firefox-via-jquery/) via Wayback Machine since the original blog was deleted.

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis` now works in firefox as well. but you have to use it in conjunction with `overflow`, it may NOT have the (default) value `visible`

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

Use this CSS class for your paragraph.

```
.single-line{
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
display: inherit;
}
```